# Storing Docker Images to Deploy in Various Regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

We are deploying an identical application that detects the region of the EC2 instance that it is deployed on so that it can use the correct configurations for various services such as RDS, Elasticache, etc. When deploying the application, should we push the image to both the East and West region? I'm just really trying to understand if there are advantages of storing the *same image* on both regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling images between regions or out to the internet will have additional latency and data transfer costs. Latency might be more of an issue if your images are large and/or you care about how quickly you're able to create a new running container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm aware of the cross-region latency. Just wondering what the best practice is, and whether it's even worth the compute time and storage to push to multiple regions

Comment: That depends on your particular usecase. If you spin up(and down) containers a lot more often then you create/publish images, I'd publish to all relevant regions - like stable versions released to production for instance. If you publish very often (like in dev), I'd stick with one region.